# Can change set with warning still be deployed?

Tags: deployment, change-set, warning

When during deploying change set to prod you get a warning like

> **long-running apex test**

Can you still successfully deploy that change set or does the warning blocks it?

Comment: What is the warning message?

Comment: long-running apex test

Comment: Missed the "change set" part. My apologies. I actually don't know if you can, I always use deployment tools these days. There's no real benefit to using change sets.

Comment: No problem :) yeah, I prefer them too. But that was not my choice to use change sets, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the change set. This warning is to indicate that deployment will take time. Once I received same message for a operation which was, as per the message running for 41 mins.

Make sure, you optimize the transactions, so that this warning will not come in next time.